# I made too many nested folders

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, java, robocopy

I made way to many nested folders, around 20 thousand, I think. I can't delete them, even with 7-Zip, as some people recomended. I tried ROBOCOPY, mirroring an empty folder, but it fails, because there's too many folders. It's not a huge problem but it annoys me a lot. I wrote a Java program to make them, just for fun, so... yeah. Any suggestions?
I would rather not reformat my hard drive, but that would probably work, because it's on my secondary drive.

Edit: Deleting the parent folder does nothing, even permanently deleting, ie no recycling bin.

Edit: Dual booting into Linux Mint and deleting the parent folder just moves it to the trash. Linux can not delete the folder either, because of file name length.

Edit: using the del \s \q *.* command doesn't work because it doesn't delete anything. Same result with just *.

Comment: Have you considered deleting the parent folder?

Comment: Can you not delete them the same way you made them?

Comment: Use a Linux bootable CD?

Comment: I do have Linux dual-booted on my pc, Will that work? or does linux also have limits

Comment: In the same folder as the created folders do `del /s *.*` in a command prompt.  That will delete all the sub-folders and files in the folder.  Make sure you're in the correct folder to prevent data loss.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and glad that you solved your problem.  However, the site's Q&A model relies on questions containing only question content and answers containing the solutions.  Can you move your solution to an answer?  In 2 days, you will be able to accept your own answer, which is how we indicate that it is solved.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Fixer1234, however it appers I was wrong about the solution working. In the future though, I will add a separate answer, as you said.

Comment: If you used a script to create it, what about a script to start deleting from the bottom and work its way to the parent?

Comment: The name is only 2 characters: `*.`

Comment: 1. Start at the bottom and work your way up (with a script).  There won't be long filenames if you start at the directory immediately above what you're deleting.  2. `*.` does not involve long filenames.  3. The question doesn't mention the directories containing files, it just talks about creating a long nest of directories.  Assuming you want to delete any files as well, use `*.*`.

Comment: Are you trying to delete from the parent directory or from the bottom of the stack (which will likely need a script)?  BTW, the parameters require forward slashes rather than backslashes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just using a script worked great. I used Java, because that's all I know, but it's probably not the best language for it. Thanks for everyone's help